# Can I say "working in Google will create great learning opportunities with highly skilled and motivated scientist colleagues surrounded"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I say

> working in Google will create great learning opportunities with highly skilled and motivated scientist colleagues surrounded ?

I have one other choice which is:

> Working in Google which full of highly skilled and motivated scientist colleagues will create great learning opportunities.

Is there any problem with these sentences? Which one is better?

Comment: **surrounded** as you have it modifies **colleagues**; but for your sentence, *you* want to be the person who is surrounded. **surrounded** is an adjective formed from the past participle of the verb **to surround**, and means "to be encircled", "to have people (or something) on all sides".    *The injured moose was being attacked by wolves. The moose was surrounded.*

Answer (score 1):

> I will have motivated colleagues *all around me*.
>
> I will have motivated colleagues surrounding me.
>
> I will be surrounded by motivated colleagues.

**around** may be stylistically better than **surrounding** here.

**colleagues all around me** means "multiple colleagues nearby", whereas **surrounding me**, although it can be used to mean  "everywhere I look" or "all over the place (where I am)", it does also connote the idea of being *encircled*.

Answer (score 0):

**Working at Google amongst such highly skilled and motivated colleagues would be a great learning opportunity for me.**

In English you work "at" a company rather than "in" it. I also believe you shouldn't say "scientist colleagues." It doesn't sound professional or eloquent. Pick one or the other.

That's my best answer based on the information you gave. If you could provide more context, I could help tailor the answer to fit appropriately.